# How to create a variable $ldir at your home directory that contains the relative path to letters?

Tags: shell, filenames, variable

If there's a directory on your Desktop called letters:

1) How to create a variable `$ldir` at your home directory that contains the relative path to letters?

2) How to copy a text file `f1.txt` to the directory letters by using the variable `$ldir`?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a variable at your home directory"? Shell variables don't have any location in the filesystem, they're entirely a construct of the running shell. Are you getting symbolic links and shell variables confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, Lets say your user is `user1` and home directory is `/home/user1/`:

```
[user1@node2 ]$ export ldir=/home/user1/Desktop/letters
[user1@node2 ]$ cp f1.txt $ldir
[user1@node2 ]$ cd ~/Desktop/letters/
[user1@node2 letters]$ ls
f1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you (if you are in a `bash` shell) to write a function instead

```
cpToLetter () { cp  "$@" ~/Desktop/letter; }
```

With a single command `cpToLetter f1.txt` you will move the file to the directory. You can use as you use cp (e.g. `cpToLetter *.txt`) but you have not to write the destination that is fixed.

If you write the function in your `~/.bashrc`, you will allow to any new shell to know that function automatically.

---

*How to write and copy* depends from the shell in which you are

In `bash` and `dash` (often `sh` is a symbolic link to `\bin\dash`)
you can write directly (without the need to specify by hand the name of the user):

```
ldir=~/Desktop/letters  
cp myfile $ldir
```

In `tcsh`

```
setenv ldir ~/Desktop/letters  
cp myfile $ldir
```